# How to copy rolling 3 values to another sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a pivot table as in Image. I would like to copy and paste the rolling last 3 months values to another sheet.  That is i need to copy NOV,DEC,JAN values to another sheet.That is Cell value A17:C17, A18:C18 and A7:C7.

For next month it must automatically copy DEC,JAN,FEB values. I used the below but i cant get the logic. I need to copy twice. First for Cells A,B,C and for cell A,D,E. How to change the code Help me

[image]

```
Sub Data()
Dim sws, dws As Worksheet
Dim lr1 As Long
Dim rng1 As Range

Set sws = Sheets("AVG")
Set dws = Sheets("Data")

lr1 = sws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng1 = Union(sws.Range("E" & lr1).Offset(-2, -4).Resize(3), sws.Range("E" & lr1).Offset(-2, -1).Resize(3), sws.Range("E" & lr1).Offset(-2).Resize(3))
rng1.Copy dws.Range("A28")

Sheets("AVG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2, -2).Resize(3, 3).Copy Sheets("Data").Range("A33")

End Sub
```

Comment: I would copy this pivot table to the new sheet and set years in rows. Then it would have been much easier.

Comment: In which cells precisely do you want the expected output for the quarter results NOV,DEC,JAN and DEC,JAN,FEB? - please edit another image or text structure.

Comment: @tm I will copy from Sheet(AVG) to another Sheet(Data)